# Open the Word Application from a button on a web page

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, ms-word, activex, office-interop

I'm developing a proof of concept web application: A web page with a button that opens the Word Application installed on the user's PC.

I'm stuck with a C# project in Visual Studio 2008 Express (Windows XP client, LAMP server). I've followed the [Writing an ActiveX Control in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dsandor/activexinnet11102005040748am/activexinnet.aspx) tutorial and after some tuning it worked fine. Then I added my button for opening Word.

The problem is that I can reference the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word from the project, but I'm not able to access it from the web page. The error says "That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers".

I've read a lot about security in .NET, but I'm totally lost now. Disclaimer: I'm into .NET since 4 days ago.

I've tried to work around this issue but I cannot see the light!! 
I don't even know if it will **ever** be possible!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions;

using System.Security;
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]

namespace OfficeAutomation
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void openWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Word.Application Word_App = null;
                Word_App = new Word.Application();
                Word_App.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't open Word application (" + exc.ToString() + ")");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note. You should understand that ActiveX works only in Internet Explorer and doesn't work in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: Are you going to require more than just opening Word? In other words, do you need to make further use of the automation interface? If not, you could just have the button initiate the download of an empty word document which will then allow the user to opt into opening word.

Comment: Yes, I need full automation; I'll download two docs and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

Using .Net Framework 4 + XBAP makes this easy: You could use WPF XBAP instead of ActiveX.

And on Project settings window do:
Signing: unckeck all boxes. (this project does not need to be signed),
under Security tab, Just change it to Full Trust.

The user will be prompted one time if he wants to allow the application to Run.

Answer (score 0):

The post [How to provide extra trust for an Internet Explorer hosted assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/26/57026.aspx) in the [.NET Security Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/) sheds light on the issue. It's dated 2003 so things could have changed now... I don't know.

But a commenter [asked](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2003/06/26/57026.aspx#1087385) (2006)

> Is it possible to execute the .net
>   assembly with all the trust permission
>   without changing anything on the
>   client side? We previously have been
>   using a signed ActiveX in a CAB that
>   was working fine, and try to port it
>   to C#.

And Shawnfa answered

> No, it is not currently possible to
>   elevate your permissions on the client
>   side for a control.  The closest
>   option is ClickOnce which will allow
>   you to prompt and elevate an
>   application -- although this
>   application will not be hosed in the
>   web page.